# Converting nucleobase representation from ASCII to UCSC .2bit

Tags: c, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bioinformatics, micro-optimization

Unambiguous DNA sequences consist only of the nucleobases adenine (A), cytosine (C), guanine (G), thymine (T). For human consumption, the bases may be represented by the corresponding `char` in either uppercase or lowercase: `A`, `C`, `G`, `T`, or `a`, `c`, `g`, `t`. This representation is inefficient, however, when long sequences need to be stored. Since only four symbols need to be stored, each symbol can be assigned a 2-bit code. The commonly used `.2bit`-format [specified](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format7) by UCSC does exactly that, using the following encoding: T = `0b00`, C = `0b01`, A = `0b10`, G = `0b11`.

The C code below shows a reference implementation written for clarity. Various open-source software that converts genomic sequences represented as a `char` sequence typically uses a 256-entry lookup table indexed by each `char` in sequence. This also isolates from the internal representation of `char`. However, memory access is energetically expensive, even if the access is to an on-chip cache, and generic table look-ups are difficult to SIMDize. It would therefore be advantageous if the conversion could be accomplished by simple integer arithmetic. Given that ASCII is the dominating `char` encoding, one  can restrict to that.

What are efficient computational approaches to convert nucleobases given as ASCII characters to their `.2bit`-representation?

```c
/* Convert nucleobases A, C, G, T represented as either uppercase or lowercase
   ASCII characters into UCSC .2bit-presentation. Passing any values other than
   those corresponding to 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'a', 'c', 'g', 't' results in an
   indeterminate response.
*/
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit (unsigned int a)
{
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_A = 2;
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_C = 1;
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_G = 3;
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_T = 0;

    switch (a) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        return UCSC_2BIT_A;
        break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        return UCSC_2BIT_C;
        break;
    case 'G':
    case 'g':
        return UCSC_2BIT_G;
        break;
    case 'T':
    case 't':
    default:
        return UCSC_2BIT_T;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is the following:

```
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit (unsigned int a)
{
    return ((0xad - a) & 6) >> 1;
}
```

This has the advantage that it needs only 8 bits, doesn't overflow, and doesn't contain non-constant shifts, so it can be immediately used to parallelize even without specific SIMD instructions, e.g. with 8 characters input in a 64-bit word

```
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_8bytes (uint64_t a)
{
    return ((0xadadadadadadadad - a) & 0x0606060606060606) >> 1;
}
```

leaving the two output bits at the bottom of each byte.

Comment: While my own "twiddle" variant is more efficient on some architectures, this is also an eminently useful variant.

Answer (score 6):

If one stares at the binary codes for the ASCII characters for the nucleobases intently, it becomes clear that bits 1 and 2 provide a unique two-bit code: `A` = `0b01000001` -> `0b00`, `C` = `0b01000011` -> `0b01`, `G` = `0b01000111` -> `0b11`, `T` = `0b01010100` -> `0b10`. Analogous for the lowercase ASCII characters, which differ merely in bit 5. Unfortunately this simple mapping does not quite match the `.2bit`-encoding, in that the codes for A and T are swapped. One way of fixing this is with a simple four-entry permutation table stored in a variable, likely assigned to a register after optimization ("in-register lookup-table"):

```c
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_perm (unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int perm = (2 << 0) | (1 << 2) | (0 << 4) | (3 << 6);
    return (perm >> (a & 6)) & 3;
}
```

An alternative method corrects the generated "naive" code from extracting bits 1 and 2 on the fly via simple bit manipulation, by observing that bit 1 is 0 for `A` and `T`, but 1 for `C` and `G`. Therefore we can swap the encodings for A and T by XOR-ing the *inverse* of bit 1 of the input with bit 1 of the preliminary code:

```c
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_twiddle (unsigned int a)
{
    return ((a >> 1) & 3) ^ (~a & 2);
}
```

This version is advantageous on processors with fast bitfield extraction instructions and low-end processors without a barrel shifter, as only a right shift by one bit position is required. On out-of-order processors this approach offers more instruction-level parallelism than the permutation table. It also seems easier to adapt to a SIMD implementation since the same shift count is used in all byte lanes.

Before I stared intently at the binary encoding of the relevant ASCII characters, I had looked into using a simple mathematical computation. A simple brute-force search over small multipliers and divisors yielded:

```c
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_math (unsigned int a)
{
    return ((18 * (a & 31)) % 41) & 3;
}
```

The multiplier `18` is friendly to processors without a fast integer multiplier. Modulo computation with a compile-time constant divisor is handled efficiently by modern compilers, and no division is required. Even so, I noticed that even the best available compilers have trouble taking advantage of the very limited range of inputs and outputs, so I had to hand-massage this to simplify the code:

```c
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_math (unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int t = 18 * (a & 31);
    return (t - ((t * 25) >> 10)) & 3;
}
```

Even in this form and assuming the availability of a single-cycle multiply this seems generally not competitive with the two prior approaches, as it yields more instructions and a longer dependency chain. However, on 64-bit platforms this entire computation can be replaced with a 64-bit, 32-entry lookup table which can give competitive performance if this 64-bit table can be placed into a register efficiently, which is the case for x86-64, where it is loaded as a immediate.

```c
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_tab (unsigned int a)
{
    uint64_t tab = ((0ULL <<  0) | (2ULL <<  2) | (0ULL <<  4) | (1ULL <<  6) |
                    (3ULL <<  8) | (0ULL << 10) | (2ULL << 12) | (3ULL << 14) |
                    (1ULL << 16) | (3ULL << 18) | (0ULL << 20) | (2ULL << 22) |
                    (3ULL << 24) | (1ULL << 26) | (2ULL << 28) | (0ULL << 30) |
                    (1ULL << 32) | (3ULL << 34) | (1ULL << 36) | (2ULL << 38) |
                    (0ULL << 40) | (1ULL << 42) | (3ULL << 44) | (0ULL << 46) |
                    (2ULL << 48) | (0ULL << 50) | (1ULL << 52) | (3ULL << 54) |
                    (0ULL << 56) | (2ULL << 58) | (3ULL << 60) | (1ULL << 62));
    return (tab >> (2 * (a & 31))) & 3;
}
```

I am appending my test framework for reference:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ORIGINAL_MATH (1)

unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_perm (unsigned int a)
{
    unsigned int perm = (2 << 0) | (1 << 2) | (0 << 4) | (3 << 6);
    return (perm >> (a & 6)) & 3;
}

unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_twiddle (unsigned int a)
{
    return ((a >> 1) & 3) ^ (~a & 2);
}

unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_math (unsigned int a)
{
#if ORIGINAL_MATH
    return ((18 * (a & 31)) % 41) & 3;
#else // ORIGINAL_MATH
    unsigned int t = 18 * (a & 31);
    return (t - ((t * 25) >> 10)) & 3;
#endif // ORIGINAL_MATH
}

unsigned int ascii_to_2bit_tab (unsigned int a)
{
    uint64_t tab = ((0ULL <<  0) | (2ULL <<  2) | (0ULL <<  4) | (1ULL <<  6) |
                    (3ULL <<  8) | (0ULL << 10) | (2ULL << 12) | (3ULL << 14) |
                    (1ULL << 16) | (3ULL << 18) | (0ULL << 20) | (2ULL << 22) |
                    (3ULL << 24) | (1ULL << 26) | (2ULL << 28) | (0ULL << 30) |
                    (1ULL << 32) | (3ULL << 34) | (1ULL << 36) | (2ULL << 38) |
                    (0ULL << 40) | (1ULL << 42) | (3ULL << 44) | (0ULL << 46) |
                    (2ULL << 48) | (0ULL << 50) | (1ULL << 52) | (3ULL << 54) |
                    (0ULL << 56) | (2ULL << 58) | (3ULL << 60) | (1ULL << 62));
    return (tab >> (2 * (a & 31))) & 3;
}

/* Convert nucleobases A, C, G, T represented as either uppercase or lowercase
   ASCII characters into UCSC .2bit-presentation. Passing any values other than
   those corresponding to 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'a', 'c', 'g', 't' results in an
   inderminate response.
*/
unsigned int ascii_to_2bit (unsigned int a)
{
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_A = 2;
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_C = 1;
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_G = 3;
    const unsigned int UCSC_2BIT_T = 0;

    switch (a) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        return UCSC_2BIT_A;
        break;
    case 'C':
    case 'c':
        return UCSC_2BIT_C;
        break;
    case 'G':
    case 'g':
        return UCSC_2BIT_G;
        break;
    case 'T':
    case 't':
    default:
        return UCSC_2BIT_T;
        break;
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    char nucleobase[8] = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'a', 'c', 'g', 't'};
    printf ("Testing permutation variant:\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof nucleobase; i++) {
        unsigned int ref = ascii_to_2bit (nucleobase[i]);
        unsigned int res = ascii_to_2bit_perm (nucleobase[i]);
        printf ("i=%2u %c res=%u ref=%u %c\n", 
                i, nucleobase[i], res, ref, (res == ref) ? 'p' : 'F');
    }
    printf ("Testing bit-twiddling variant:\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof nucleobase; i++) {
        unsigned int ref = ascii_to_2bit (nucleobase[i]);
        unsigned int res = ascii_to_2bit_twiddle (nucleobase[i]);
        printf ("i=%2u %c res=%u ref=%u %c\n", 
                i, nucleobase[i], res, ref, (res == ref) ? 'p' : 'F');
    }
    printf ("Testing math-based variant:\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof nucleobase; i++) {
        unsigned int ref = ascii_to_2bit (nucleobase[i]);
        unsigned int res = ascii_to_2bit_math (nucleobase[i]);
        printf ("i=%2u %c res=%u ref=%u %c\n", 
                i, nucleobase[i], res, ref, (res == ref) ? 'p' : 'F');
    }
    printf ("Testing table-based variant:\n");
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof nucleobase; i++) {
        unsigned int ref = ascii_to_2bit (nucleobase[i]);
        unsigned int res = ascii_to_2bit_tab (nucleobase[i]);
        printf ("i=%2u %c res=%u ref=%u %c\n", 
                i, nucleobase[i], res, ref, (res == ref) ? 'p' : 'F');
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: In the question, you wrote *generic table look-ups are difficult to SIMDize*.  But the unique low 2 bits means it's no longer "generic".  Might be hard to write in portable C that can *auto*-vectorize to an x86 `pshufb` or ARM `tbl` (I think that's their byte shuffle?).  But if manually vectorizing, you could pack pairs of ASCII codes down to 4-bit nibbles, keeping the low 2 bits of each.  Then map nibbles to the correct UCSC codes with a 16-byte LUT in parallel (high garbage in each byte is ok, except for the high bit for pshufb; AVX-512 vpermb doesn't care).  Then pack adjacent nibbles

Comment: Extract the two bits using `shift/unpack/pmovmskb` then just fix that up with `x ^= ((~x & 0x5555) << 1)`.

Comment: @PeterCordes By "generic table lookup" I meant idioms seen in existing open-source code like `bVal = ntValNoN[(int)*in++];`, where `ntValNoN` is a 256-entry table, and `in` points to a sequence of `char`. That is what prompted me to look at the details more closely, and staring at the ASCII representation I *then* noticed that bits 1 and 2 provide a unique code suitable for post processing. I haven't gotten around to the actual SIMDization yet.

Comment: I'd missed that you said bits 2:1, not bits 1:0.  And I didn't find any `+`, `^`, or `|` combination of two ASCII codes that's unique in the low 4 bits for all 16 pairs without masking before the first combining step, e.g. `((p[1] << 1) + (p[0]>>1)) & 0xf` has a couple repeats when checking with `for p in itertools.product(bases, repeat=2): print( attempt )`.  I think we can still use a table lookup more efficiently than `ascii_to_2bit_twiddle` before packing, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/cPEdscdh7 shows masking, shifting, and packing before a final shift and pshufb.

Comment: Or of course we could pshufb on the initial ASCII data before `psrlw` / `por` / `packuswb` because its high bit is clear, but that's trading a pand for a pshufb ahead of pack, and just saving one `psrlw` per pair of vectors after pack.  And creating a bottleneck on shuffle throughput on Intel CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes For now I am still working on semi-portable SIMD-in-a-register, The following seems suitable across ARM and x86, where unaligned access is supported: `uint8_t compress4 (char *in) { uint32_t a; memcpy (&a, in, sizeof a); a = ((a >> 1) & 0x03030303) ^ (~a & 0x02020202); /* convert representation*/ a = (a * 0x40100401) >> 24; /* pack */ return a; }`

Comment: SIMD packed 32-bit multiply is not great on many x86 CPUs; `pmulld` is 2 dependent uops (so about 10c latency for OoO exec to hide), and the uops can only run on one or two ports.  Still, for packing 4 fields to one in a single step, it's maybe worth it.  Of course if compilers fail to vectorize at all and just go scalar, then scalar `imul` is totally fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am looking at replacements for 3 existing functions that compress 4, 8, and 16 nucleobases, respectively. Every size can use a different approach.  Solutions based on dedicated SIMD instruction sets would seem to make sense for the 16-nucleobase compressor; the other ones should be fine with plain integer arithmetic. So I am not trying to [auto-]vectorized the `compress4` code I showed. If you wanted to create a self-answered question with an AVX2 implementation of a 16-wide compressor, I'd be happy to upvote that. Note nucleotide order: `bval=tab[*in++]; out=(out<<2)+bval;`

Comment: For long sequences, you'd likely be best off with a function that produces 16 (or 32) bytes of packed *output*, from 64 or 128 bytes of input.  That way, any work you can defer until after packing can be done once per 2 vectors, or once per 4 vectors.  e.g. maybe the XOR bit-flip correction can be deferred to that point, instead of an earlier LUT or doing it on a less-dense representation of the data.  (Thanks for the reminder about the weird "big endian" order of nucleotides within a byte; I noticed that in the spec but forgot when playing with stuff on Godbolt.)

Answer (score 1):

The following routine will fill an array of `uint32_t` values with the contents of an ASCII string filled with the characters you stated and will conserve the state in order to be able to append a second, third, etc. number of strings to the array.  The way of using it is illustrated with a `main()` routine that takes the string arguments from the command line and passes them to an array of `TOTAL` elements.  The parameters to the routine are described in the comment above it.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define UCSC_2BIT_T  (0)
#define UCSC_2BIT_C  (1)
#define UCSC_2BIT_A  (2)
#define UCSC_2BIT_G  (3)

#define PAIRS_PER_INTEGER   16

/**
 * Converts a string of nucleobases in ASCII form into an array
 * of 32bit integers in 2bitform.  As it should be possible to
 * continue the array of integers, a status reference is
 * maintained in order to determine determine where in the
 * integer to start putting the two bit sequences.  For this,
 * a (*state) variable is maintained (initialize it to 0) to
 * remember where to start putting bitpairs in the array.
 *
 * @param state_ref reference to the state variable to be maintained
 *               with the position on which to put the base in the
 *               array entry.
 * @param dna    string with the ASCII chain of bases.
 * @param twobit array reference to start filling.
 * @param sz     size of the array ***in array entries***.
 * @return the number of array elements written.  This allows to
 *         use a pointer and advance it at each function call
 *         with the number of entries consumed on each call.
 */
ssize_t
dna2twobit(
    int *state_ref,
    char *dna,
    uint32_t twobit[],
    size_t sz)
{
    /* local copy so we only change the state in case of
     * successful execution */
    int state = 30 - *state_ref;
    if (state == 30) *twobit = 0;
    ssize_t total_nb = 0; /* total number of array elements consumed */
    while (*dna && sz) {
        char base = toupper(*dna++);
        uint32_t tb;
        switch (base) {
        case 'A': tb = UCSC_2BIT_A; break;
        case 'C': tb = UCSC_2BIT_C; break;
        case 'T': tb = UCSC_2BIT_T; break;
        case 'G': tb = UCSC_2BIT_G; break;
        default: return -1;
        }
        *twobit |= tb << state;
        state -= 2;
        if (state < 0) {
            --sz; ++twobit;
            state += 32;
            *twobit = 0;
            total_nb++;
        }
    }
    *state_ref = 30 - state;
    return total_nb;
}
```

This function can be linked separately into any program you wish, but I have provide a `main()` code to illustrate the use of the function.  You can call the program with the actual chains in ASCII encoded in the command line parameters.  The program will encode them one after the previous in order to  demonstrate multi conversion (16 bases fit in one 32bit integer, as stated by the definition of the format you posted in the question, so in case not a multiple of 16 have been encoded, the status reflects how many bits have been covered in the last one.

The code continues with the main function below:

```
#define TOTAL 16

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int state = 0, i;
    uint32_t twobit_array[TOTAL], *p = twobit_array;
    size_t twobit_cap = TOTAL;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("Adding the following chain: [%s]\n", argv[i]);
        ssize_t n = dna2twobit(
                        &state,
                        argv[i],
                        p,
                        twobit_cap);
        if (n < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    "argument invalid: %s\n"
                    "continuing to next\n",
                    argv[i]);
            continue;
        }
        twobit_cap -= n;
        p += n;
    }
    if (!state) --p;
    uint32_t *q = twobit_array;
    size_t off = 0;
    for (int j = 0; q <= p; j++) {
        char *sep = "";
        printf("%09zd: ", off);
        for (int k = 0; k < 4 && q <= p; k++) {
            printf("%s%08x", sep, *q);
            sep = "-";
            q++;
            off += 16;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you not notice the [micro-optimization] tag?  Your `switch` compiles with a chain of cmp/jcc in GCC, or with an indirect jmp in clang. https://godbolt.org/z/53WdoMxYW And `*twobit |= tb << state;` compiles to a memory-destination `or`, so even if you replaced the switch with an efficient function from another answer, you're still creating a dependency chain through memory that's 6 cycles long per nucleotide.  (And since it's uint32_t output, the chain is 16 steps long, so on a typical x86 with 6-cycle ALU+store-forwarding latency that's 16 x 6 = 96 cycles of latency to try to hide).

Comment: Not to mention that `toupper` is locale-aware, and compiles to a non-inline function call on GNU/Linux (`call __ctype_toupper_loc`).  So that's also significantly slower than just masking away the high bits.  So basically this seems like a safe reference implementation, not optimized.  (Also apparently checking the `char*` for a C string terminator as well as an explicit length?)

Comment: @PeterCordes, well, that's true, but as  you see, I have not used `setlocale()` in the code, and `toupper()` IMHO is going to have no locale dependencies for the ASCII characters `'A'`, `'G'`, `'C'` and `'T'`.  The program will default to the `C` locale (ASCII) and probably will run the same despite the locale you select. Aminoacids are not locale dependant, so using the default `C` locale would suffice.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I have read in many places that a `switch` normally compiles into a table of jumps, which is not the case with a chain of `if` statements.  What can be Gcc is completely out of scope as the tags don't mention gcc.  Creating, an ASCII jump table for any character fully populated with NULLs except 4 entries  I think is worthless considering, as using the offset from `'A'` would require a subtraction to handle.  So for readability and maintainability, I assumed the best solution was the swich statement, despite what the gcc guys decide is better suited for it.

Comment: Historically, ctype has used macro expansion, if you take the care to `#include <ctype.h>` which you see I do in my code.  Read K&R for documentation about `toupper()`.

Comment: An indirect jump per character is horrible, that's the point of this question!  It's possible with a couple arithmetic operations, if you don't need to detect invalid input.  (Which the question and self-answer already implies isn't necessary.)  I think you're completely missing the point of this micro-optimization question.  The way it compiles on current real-world compilers is extremely relevant.  (re: toupper, K&R may predate locale support.  And obviously this *is* a macro or builtin, but the expansion still involves a non-inline function `__ctype_toupper_loc`.)

Comment: I haven't only "criticized" other answers, only this one; my comments under the other answer were of a different nature.  The fact that I haven't gotten around to expanding my [godbolt attempt in comments under njuffa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639594/converting-nucleobase-representation-from-ascii-to-ucsc-2bit/70650930?noredirect=1#comment124884134_70639595) into an answer of my own doesn't make this a better answer.  Some of the things I identified in this answer are easily fixable, like keeping `*twobit` in a local var for the inner loop.

Comment: @Luis Colorado Is there a typo (`&&` instead of `&`) with the loop: `for (int k = 0; k < 4 & q <= p; k++)`  Trying to digest your code.

Comment: @Yifangt, thanks for the note, you're right.  Corrected!!!